# struts2 validate

Tags: java, validation, struts2

In Struts2 you can change the method used for execution for an action by changing the method attribute in the following line:

```
<action name="registerVal" class="cz.vutbr.fit.pishotel.model.action.Register" method="execute">
```

Is it possible to change the validation method used as well, or is the validate method name hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

It hard coded in the following way.  If you have:

```
<action name="registerVal" class="cz.vutbr.fit.pishotel.model.action.Register" method="myMethod">
```

Then the validation interceptor will call

```
public void validateMyMethod() {

if (someValue == null) {

addFieldError("myField","myMessage");

}

}
```

If there are errors in the fieldErrors collection then INPUT will be returned for registerVal